# Serial Monitor shows random texts While Reading Data from RTC DS3231 with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, c++, ds3231-alarms

I tried to set time on a RTC DS3231. After Uploading it with Arduino IDE, I try viewing the output in the Serial Monitor. However, if I start viewing the Serial Monitor, It starts showing encrypted lines. I have tried the example code and yet it shows the same.

The Setup code

```
#include <DS3231.h>
DS3231  rtc(SDA, SCL);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  rtc.begin();


  rtc.setDOW(SUNDAY);    
  rtc.setTime(02, 17, 0);   
  rtc.setDate(29, 03, 2020);  
}
```

The loop code

```
void loop()
{
  Serial.print(rtc.getDOWStr());
  Serial.print(" ");


  Serial.print(rtc.getDateStr());
  Serial.print(" -- ");

  Serial.println(rtc.getTimeStr());

  delay (1000);
}
```

The output Screen Shot is [image: the output screenshot]

Comment: change the baud rate in Serial Monitor to match the baud rate set in sketch

Comment: Normally, you shouldn't show text as an embedded picture or video. Here everybody can see the wrong baud rate. :) Thanks for registering to StackExchange for this issue.